# changing attributes of product view in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a section of extra information for the product. In the config you can add a link. This is showing the text of the link, but we want to have a word as a link and not the url to be seen.

For the product additional information there is now 1 working link. **(a word that is the link instead of showing the url)**

Now for a second field *(second link)*, I want to do the same. When this field is filled with an url, the word *"second link*" must be the link, but not showing the url. The word *"second link"* is the link

I tried to change the attributes.phtml but I get lost changing the php code.

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <tr class="<?php if ($_data['value'] == "No" or $_data['value']== "Nee" or $_data['value'] == "N/A" or $_data['value'] == "Nvt" ){?>no-data-value<?php } ?>">
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>          
            <td class="data">
            <?php if($_data['code'] == 'link'){?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_data['value']?>"target="_blank" class="link-manufacturer"><?php echo $this->__('Product page manufacturer')?></a>
            <?php }else{?>
              <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
              <?php }?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I am trying to do the same for the second field. How do I change this in the php? I tried several things but ends up in a loop showing it twice or i get an error in the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the code below:

```
    <?php 
    $links = array('link' => 'Product page manufacturer',
    'YOUR_CODE_OF_SECOND_LINK' => 'TEXT_FOR_SECOND_LINK');
     foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <tr class="<?php if ($_data['value'] == "No" or $_data['value']== "Nee" or $_data['value'] == "N/A" or $_data['value'] == "Nvt" ){?>no-data-value<?php } ?>">
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>          
            <td class="data">
            <?php if(array_key_exists($_data['code'], $links)){
            $code = $_data['code']; ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_data['value']?>"target="_blank" class="link-manufacturer"><?php echo $this->__($links[$code])?></a>
            <?php }else{?>
              <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
              <?php }?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

You will be able to add links' codes and texts to the $links array. It's not very good to edit template files by this way, but it should work.